# Xamarin.forms ios Native Crash in custom ButtonRenderer

Tags: xamarin.forms

I updated Xamarin.forms package from nuget to 5.0.0.2244. The package has been updated both in common and iOS projects.

I created a custom renderer for a button element. The first lines of the renderer are:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(AppButton), typeof(AppButtonRenderer))]
 namespace com.app.iOS.Renderers
{
public class AppButtonRenderer : ButtonRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Button> e)
    {
        try
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
```

Before the update, when execution executed *base.OnElementChanged* method everything has gone right, but now I'm getting a stack trace like the one following this issue. Same thing happens with Xamarin.Forms 5.0.0.2196. What's wrong?

Infos:

Visual Studio: 16.11.7

Thank you in advance

```
=================================================================
    Native Crash Reporting
=================================================================
Got a segv while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

=================================================================
    Native stacktrace:
=================================================================

    0x1043f81e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_dump_native_crash_info
    0x1043eec5c - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_handle_native_crash

    0x1044aee08 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x10458a0e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x10458f9d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
    0x104590548 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arm64_common_trampoline

    0x104591748 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1043fee70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1044ab984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked

/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abaa6180 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abaa6544 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1044ab984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1044aee08 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x10458a0e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x10458f9d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampoline
    0x104590548 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arm64_common_trampoline
    0x1abaa1958 - 
    0x10459dc04 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x10459c2c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1045931b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x1abaabbe0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abaac3a0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab98bddc - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab991ea0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

    0x1043fbbb8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_sigsegv_signal_handler_debug
    0x1f527c29c - /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1aaa53d94 - /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation : <redacted>
    0x10459dc34 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x10459c2c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1045931b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x104591748 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1043fee70 - /private/var
    0x10459db78 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x10459c2c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1045931b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full

    0x1ab98b664 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab988984 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac20fd7c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac20f444 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac210348 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac221888 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

e

    0x104591748 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1043fee70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1044ab984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1044aee08 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke
    0x10458a0e0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_invoke_trampoline
    0x10458f9d4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arch_trampolin
    0x104590548 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_arm64_common_trampoline
    0x1ac1caa08 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

    0x1ac1cc49c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac1d25e8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab826598 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abd8f634 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : _UIScenePerformActionsWithLifecycleActionMask
    0x1ab827130 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab826bf0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab826f40 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab82677c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab82ecc0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abc9d04c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1abda8444 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/
UIKitCore : _UISceneSettingsDiffActionPerformChangesWithTransitionContext
    0x1ab82e9b8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab6568a0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab655220 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ab6564c8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac1d0788 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>

    0x1abcc66ac - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1b8d495d8 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1b8d74d44 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1b8d586a4 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1b8d74a0c - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1a93da7ec - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1a93de2dc - /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib : <redacted>
    0x1b8d9cfa0 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1b8d9cc30 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1b8d9d184 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/FrontBoardServices.framework/FrontBoardServices : <redacted>
    0x1a9767848 - /System/Library/Framewo
rks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a9767744 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a9766ab4 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a9760a28 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : <redacted>
    0x1a97601c0 - /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation : CFRunLoopRunSpecific
    0x1c0d48734 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices : GSEventRunModal
    0x1ac1ce7e4 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : <redacted>
    0x1ac1d4054 - /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore : UIApplicationMain
    0x10459db90 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x10459c2c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS
.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1045931b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x104591748 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1043fee70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1044ab984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1044b2000 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_try_invoke_array
    0x10445b4f0 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.
==============================================================
Memory around native instruction pointer (0x1f527c640):0x1f527c630  21 00 05 8b 20 04 40 ac 21 80 00 91 42 00 05 cb  !... .@.!...B...
0x1f527c640  02 0c 00 ac 42 00 01 f1 e9 00 00 54 60 04 00 ac  ....B......T`...
0x1f527c650  63 80 00 91 20 04 40 ac 21 80 00 91 42 80 00 f1  c... .@.!...B...
0x1f527c660  68 ff ff 54 21 00 02 8b 22 0c 40 ac 60 04 00 ac  h..T!...".@.`...

=================================================================
    Managed Stacktrace:
=================================================================
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_UIntPtr <0x00022>
      at Foundation.NSMutableData:AppendBytes <0x00054>
      at Foundation.NSData:FromStream <0x0010c>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.EmbeddedFontLoader:LoadFont <0x00016>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Internals.FontRegistrar:HasFont <0x0013e>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FontExtensions:CleanseFontName <0x0000c>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iO
0x00228>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <0x00228>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <0x00228>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:Cre
S.FontExtensions:_ToNativeFont <0x00124>
      at System.Func`4:invoke_TResult_T1_T2_T3 <0x000ae>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FontExtensions:ToNativeFont <0x000b4>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FontExtensions:ToNativeFont <0x0005c>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FontExtensions:ToUIFont <0x0000a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer:UpdateFont <0x00022>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.ButtonRenderer:OnElementChanged <0x00150>
      at com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.Renderers.AppButtonRenderer:OnElementChanged <0x00012>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <0x002a2>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <
iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke
    0x10446b780 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : ves_icall_InternalInvoke_raw
    0x10459db90 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall
    0x10459c2c4 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : do_icall_wrapper
    0x1045931b8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_exec_method_full
    0x104591748 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : interp_runtime_invoke
    0x1043fee70 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.
PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_runtime_invoke
    0x1044ab984 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_invoke_checked
    0x1044b0bf8 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_runtime_exec_main_checked
    0x1043e3850 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : mono_jit_exec
    0x10458f814 - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : xamarin_main
    0x1043ab4cc - /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/4A837479-2E23-4698-9E24-0A8CFB635F64/com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.app/Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS : main
    0x1a941ccf8 - /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib : <redacted>

=================================================================
    Basic Fault Address Reporting
===
ateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <0x00228>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:SetElement <0x00228>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementRenderer`1:Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.IVisualElementRenderer.SetElement <0x00010>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:OnChildAdded <0x00084>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementPackager:Load <0x0005a>
      at Xamari
006e>
      at com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.AppDelegate:FinishedLaunching <0x0006e>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_bool__this___UIApplication_NSDictionary <0x000c8>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain <0x000b8>
      at UIKit.UIApplication:Main <0x00054>
      at com.v2home.v2AppTool.iOS.Application:Main <0x00012>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:InternalInvoke <0x00030>
      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo:Invoke <0x000fc>
      at System.Reflection.MethodBase:Invoke <0x0001a>
      at Xamarin.iOS.HotRestart.Application:Run <0x001c8>
      at Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS.Applications:Main <0x0005a>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void_string[] <0x00092>
=================================================================

n.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer:ViewDidLoad <0x0010c>
      at System.Object:runtime_invoke_direct_void__this__ <0x0008e>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Messaging:IntPtr_objc_msgSendSuper <0x0001a>
      at UIKit.UIViewController:get_View <0x0006c>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer:get_NativeView <0x00016>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PageRenderer:SetElement <0x00096>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:CreateRenderer <0x00080>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:AddChild <0x00052>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.Platform:WillAppear <0x00086>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.PlatformRenderer:ViewWillAppear <0x00040>
      at <Module>:runtime_invoke_direct_void__this___bool <0x0009e>
      at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
      at ObjCRuntime.Messaging:void_objc_msgSend <0x0001a>
      at UIKit.UIWindow:MakeKeyAndVisible <0x00038>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate:SetMainPage <0x00022>
      at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate:FinishedLaunching <0x0
```

**Update**

The problem is the font reference in this class

```
[assembly: ExportFont("Orbitron-Bold.ttf", Alias = "OrbitronBold")]
namespace com.App.Controls
{
    public class AppButton:Button
    {
        public AppButton()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

When I comment the font reference everything works. What I've to understand now is what happened during the library update because the code is exactly the same as before.

Check my last comment

Comment: Looks like there is some code missing for your custom renderer :)

Comment: @Gerald Versluis Has something changed? This code works fine before visual studio and xamarin.forms update

Comment: I've just tested a project with a custom ios buttonrenderer, updated it to that XForms version. Did not crash. I see this line in your stack dump `EmbeddedFontLoader:LoadFont`. Manage nugets for solution - see if other nugets need updates.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you are right. Me too I tried to create a new app with an ios custom renderer and everything executed well. I updated my post, and problem is the font reference.

Comment: It looks like a known [problem](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/14905)